# class property not recognized when imported

Tags: python, class, import

I've run into an issue where an imported class is not able to recognize some of its own properties.  The following describes the class in stringmanager.py

```
    class String_Manager:
        def __init__(self):
            self.jsonformat = None
            self.createjsonformat()


        def createjsonformat(self)
            with open("formatefile.json") as f:
                self.jsonformat = json.load(f)
            self.jsonformat["Server"] = "Server"
            self.jsonformat["Payload"] = "Payload"
            return copy.deepcopy(self.jsonformat)

    stringManager = String_Manager()
```

Elsewhere the stringManager is imported

```
    from stringmanager import stringManager
    uploadtype = stringManager.jsonformat
```

Yet I am getting an error that states:
"AttributeError: 'String_Manager' object has no attribute 'jsonformat'.  Other examples that I have looked at attribute this to improper inheritance of a mix of tabs and spaces.  Yet this codebase that I am working with uses no parent classes and adheres to PEP8 standards, thus there are not tabs/spaces combinations.  Are there any other procedures that need to be followed when importing an object from another python file?

Comment: Please post **an actual snippet of code you have tried**. This clearly isn't a real example because there's a typo in `stringManger`. Because you did not post a **real example that you have actually tried**, it is unclear whether you are importing the `stringManager` instance or the `String_Manger` class.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `jsonformat` attribute of your class is created on the `__init__` function, it will only exist on initialised instances of your class, not the pure class object. You would need to do `uploadtype = String_Manager().jsonformat` for it to work.

EDIT: It has been correctly pointed out that the OP is trying to import the instance itself, in which case my answer doesn't really apply. However, I haven't been able to reproduce the issue, although there is a problem with the original code where the `jsonformat` should be defined as a dictionary instead of None, or else the `createjsonformat` method will fail.

Comment: But he instantiates a ```String_Manager``` object as ```stringManager``` and then imports the object in

Comment: @wnnmaw, that's what the OP **says** he is doing but since his code contains a simple typo which would have caused a **different** error, we don't know if this is what he is actually doing.

Comment: @Dan I appreciate you pointing out my spelling errors, and I apologize that I cannot post the original code.  As you can see I am new to the stackoverflow community and am not currently aware that this was manditory.  wnnmaw is correct in his mention that I am trying to import an instantiated object.

Comment: Even if you cannot post the original code, post a **complete, simple example** that produces a problem analogous to one that you describe (as a bonus, you may figure out how to solve your own problem along the way!). The error you encounter does not correspond in any meaningful way to the code you actually posted; I tried it and it works as expected once the spelling is fixed. So that leaves us trying to guess how your actual code is different from the code you've posted.

Comment: The solution I came to was to manually call the helper functions which populate 'self.jsonformat'  for some reason they were not automatically executed when the stringManager  object was instantiated.  I was under the impression that the __init__ function would execute when String_Manager() is called, but in my case the functions nested inside __init__ were not being executed.  Not sure why...

Comment: The parts of the code you posted imported and workd just fine (after fixing the other issues). Calling `String_Manager()` should certainly execute the `__init__` function (you could put a print statement somewhere to see). Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to tell why it doesn't work for you.